# How to set different paths under compilerOptions, depending on env variable

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, tsconfig

In my angular application I need to conditionally load modules depending on which environment the app is running (dev/prod). In the development environment it should be pointing to the libs folder of my local project, and for the production one it should point to an external package in the `node_modules` folder.

I have already tried to use the ternary operator as follows:

```
import { ModuleA as ModuleAExternal } from '@external/moduleA';
import { ModuleA } from '@moduleA';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    environment.production ?   ModuleAExternal : ModuleA
  ]
})
```

Which works, but when the project is build I dont want to be forced to import both local and external packages.

So i would expect that the same

```
import { ModuleA } from '@moduleA';
```

would point to either the local lib or the external npm package depending on the environment. Since the `@moduleA` path is set in the tsconfig.json file under the `compilerOptions` as `paths`, is there a way to make this separation there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have different environment file for `development` and `production` environments, from there you can define the moduleA. So let say they're `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` (for prod)

in `environment.ts` you an add

```
import { ModuleA } from '@moduleA';

export const environment = {
  ...
  ModuleA: ModuleA,
  ...
```

and in `environment.prod.ts`

```
import { ModuleA } from '@external/moduleA';

export const environment = {
  ...
  ModuleA: ModuleA,
  ...
```

So you can write them as

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    environment.ModuleA
  ]
})
```

Hope this help

Comment: Can we do the same without environment files ? I have a similar requirement, but without environment files.

Comment: You can use Angular dependency provider to achieve the same result https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers